# Unable to find AsNoTracking in Abp.Zero.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, abp

I'm using [ASP.NET Boiler](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) Plate for developing the web application. I'm using `Abp.Zero.EntityFramework` as an O/RM framework. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find `AsNoTracking` extension method.

I'm using `Abp.Domain.Repositories` and injecting them into my code.

```
private readonly IRepository<StaffBankAccount> _staffBankAccountRepository;
public StaffBankAccountAppService(IRepository<StaffBankAccount> staffBankAccountRepository)
{
    _staffBankAccountRepository = staffBankAccountRepository;
}
```

Here is my code where I want to use `AsNoTracking`

```
var staffAccounts = _staffBankAccountRepository.AsNoTracking().GetAll().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == input.Id);
```

But unfortunately, this show `AsNoTracking()` is not defined.

How we can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`.AsNoTracking()` applies to an `IQueryable` so you can't call it on an `IRepository`.

```cs
var staffAccounts = _staffBankAccountRepository.GetAll()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == input.Id);
```